# How can Microsoft Word restrict files when saving them as PDF?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, restrictions

If PDF files are being created via Microsoft Word's "Save as" dialog, how can they be restricted (from text being edited, copied, printed, etc.)?

I'm **not** talking about encrypting the file to being opened only with a password.

Comment: Is the source Word document protected?

Comment: Are you saying you want to make it "view-only"?  There's no way to create all of those restrictions in Word's save-as dialog.

Comment: Yes, "view-only".

Comment: Protection is an "it depends" topic, and we need to know what this situation depends on in order to get the correct solution. If you're in a domain environment, protection could be via permissions. Adobe offers some protection features in the PDF format, but Word doesn't really have a way to implement these to my knowledge, and any program can simply ignore them if it so desires. So, if you could explain more the sort of environment these files are being produced and disseminated in, we'd be able to get you a good answer that should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting to an image per page first and then generating the PDF as a series of images.  Same thing can happen if you export a PDF from a google docs file, you can pick "editable" or not.  Editable lets you copy/paste since it is text, protected is images.

Of course, if you have such a PDF file it can always be OCR scanned and converted back to text....

Comment: Wow, that's Google's solution...?

Comment: @LWC no idea if that really happens but one of the `pdftk` tools strips one tiff per page out and it is the perfect page text, no borders.  So effectively... yes?